# jsrender/jsreport - How to print a variable an all the pages

Tags: printing, header, repeat, jsrender, jsreport

I'm using jsreport and using jsrender engine to generate PDF reports.

I want to print some variables on all the pages (but not in the page header or footer), and also a header of a table should appear on all pages. How Can I specify to print something on all pages ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be potentially do-able with thead tag, which by default prints on each page of the long table

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><td>Repeated thing here</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>....</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Unfortunately this is very buggy in all printing engines, so you may have problems with it, some workarounds are mentioned here https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10927

Comment: It seems that sometimes it overlaps and for the moment I couldn't find a workaround.